# Google apps script - variable reset during iteration

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, closures, global-variables

I would expect global variable iii to increment but iii remains = 1 throughout until max stack size reached.

```
var iii = 1; //this is supposed to be global variable declaration in google apps script

function tryglobal() {
  for (iii = 1; iii < 100; iii++)  {
    console.log(iii);
    iii = iii*2;
    tryglobal();
  }
}
```

but iii always remain 1 till stack overflow in google apps script.

Why so? Is it due to processing of each iteration seperately?

Comment: You do understand that at each iteration of the loop you launch an infinite recursion into `tryglobal`, right? `iii=1` reassigns the value to 1, `iii *= 2` multiplies by 2. Everything is repeated ad infinitum. At some point the number of functions allocated on stack overflows, hence the error.

Comment: Specifically `for (iii=1;` resets `iii` to 1

Comment: @TheMaster I agree, but there has (?) to be a goal for doing something. Otherwise how can we define a more optimal way of achieving the same goal ?

Comment: @Marios Why should there be? The question here is simply  "why?" Why does this happen? Nothing else.

Comment: @TheMaster because that looks (to me) like a school homework assignment. Of course I can be mistaken and I hope so.

Comment: @Marios I wonder which school teaches  global variables in "Google apps script"  specifically.

Comment: @TheMaster I wish mine would do haha. Maybe it is a JavaScript question. Anyway, I didn't downvote this question nor I mind these types of questions. But to me the issue would be clearer if there was a goal, is all. Anyway, good answer.

Comment: Hey, Respect, but don’t make fun of a newby. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

The for-loop initialization expression resets `iii` to 1 on each recursion

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:false,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
var iii=1; //this is supposed to be global variable declaration in google apps script

function tryglobal() 
{
for (iii=1;iii<100;iii++) 
  {console.log(iii);
  iii=iii*2;
  tryglobal();
  }
}
tryglobal()
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

#### Solution:

Avoid resetting `iii` to 1 in `for()` loop initializer

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:false,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
var iii=1; //this is supposed to be global variable declaration in google apps script

function tryglobal() 
{
for (;iii<100;iii++) 
  {console.log(iii);
  iii=iii*2;
  tryglobal();
  }
}
tryglobal()
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

#### References:

- [For loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: I was expecting output like 1,2,4,8,16. I think this should work. I will try and report. Thanks @TheMaster

Comment: @jmd Click the "run snippet" , you'll see expected output

Comment: This works perfectly @TheMaster, thanks. I am a sort of newby. So did not know this syntax.

Comment: @jmd Consider accepting the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

Every time that you executes a function from the script editor, the UI or from a trigger, the whole project is loaded, meaning the `iii` is set to `1`;

By the other hand your function calls itself on each iteration of the for loop, which sets `iii=1`, so it enters in some sort of "infinite loop" and never reaches the end of the first iteration (meaning it will never execute `i++`);

Because `console.log` is before `iii=iii*2;`, your log never will show other thing than `1`.

Suggestion 1

1. Add console.log after each modification of `iii`.
2. As was mentioned in the TheMaster's answer you could omit the first arument of loop, to avoid `iii` to be "reset"
3. You should avoid write code that enters in "infinite loops". In order to do this you should include an exit condition

```
var iii=1; //this is supposed to be global variable declaration in google apps script
console.log(iii);

function tryglobal() 
{
for (;iii<100;iii++) 
  {console.log(iii);
  iii=iii*2;
  console.log(iii);
  /** The following line is only "required" if you include the first argument and you are 
   not sure how your for statement will work */
  if(iii < 5) return; 
  }
}
```

Comment: This  condition `iii<100;` is enough to exit. In fact, that's what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @TheMaster You are right that the condition is enough in order to do what the OP is trying to do, thanks. I add a comment to the code.